# Tagging in gitlab CI running multiple times

Tags: automation, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I created GitLab job to create git tag and push to the repository as following:

```
  add tag:
  extends: .install_dependencies
  stage: deploy
  image:
    name: nexus-docker.ship.gov.sg/python:latest
    entrypoint: ["/bin/bash"]
  script:
    - echo "This job deploys something from the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH branch."
    - git tag -a v"$VERSION" -m version"$VERSION"
    - git push origin v"$VERSION"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
```

But every-time I pushed from my commit branch, the pipeline is triggered by 2 times: from branch and then tag.
Since the tag is already created in first pipeline, then the second triggered by tag is failed. I only want to make run one time for this job based on the rules.

[image: pipeline triggered 2 times for same commit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Gitlab CI yaml there is a keyword `except:` to tell the CI when not to run. What you'll want to do is add this to the task so it only runs once to tag, and then ignores the tag when that comes. This is what your pipeline script might look like:

```yaml
  add tag:
  extends: .install_dependencies
  stage: deploy
  ...
  except:
    - tags

  script:
    - echo "This job deploys something from the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH branch."
  ...
```

Comment: Not entirely sure about the placement in the script, but the idea and keyword remain the same, :). I am sure Gitlab CI's linter will help you out.

Comment: it works now. let's say if i want to run only master branch, then should be like this? 
  except:
    - tags
  only:
    - master

Comment: I mean, you'll have to try it and see, :D. But, yes. That looks right. If my answer was correct, it would be great if you could accept it, so it can get visibility.

Comment: That's great to hear. Nothing is better than seeing that magical green check-mark, and knowing your pipeline is running well, :).